# fnmatch- relating to matching a particular kind of filenames with numbers

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to list all the files in a directory which match `abc_def_[somenumber].json`. For example `abc_def_001.json` could be a file.

```
import os, re,fnmatch
pattern = 'abc_def_*'
for f in os.listdir('path of folder'):
   if fnmatch.fnmatch(f, pattern):
      print f
```

But this is not quite accurate as it spits out `"abc_def_comparison_001.json"`. I tried

```
pattern = 'abc_def_[0-9*]'
```

but that didn't quite work either. any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

with unix-style pattern matching that `fnmatch` or `glob` provides, the closest you could do would be:

```
pattern = 'abc_def_[0-9]*.json'
```

(would match `abc_def_122.json`, not `abc_def_something.json` but would wrongly match `abc_def_12hello.json`). For your example it does the job:

```
>>> fnmatch.fnmatch("abc_def_comparison_001.json",'abc_def_[0-9]*.json')
False
>>> fnmatch.fnmatch("abc_def_001.json",'abc_def_[0-9]*.json')
True
>>>
```

of course with regular expressions you could match what you want:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("abc_def_\d+\.json")
```

and in the loop

```
if pattern.match(f):
```

throw in `re.IGNORECASE` as second argument to the `compile` method if you're using windows, so it behaves like `fnmatch` regarding the casing.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
pattern = r"abc_def_[\d]+(\.json)"
```

Match:

- `"abc_def_"` literally
- one or more digits
- `".json"` literally

See the pattern on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/MmGs1J/3/).

Comment: Isn't that a regex though? The question is asking for a solution in the pattern used by `fnmatch`.